# wifi problem in new Ideapad 320E: it is very unstable

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my new Ideapad 320E and I have an issue of unstable wifi (I had touchpad issues but they were solved after an upgrade).

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

[image: terminal]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: sir i have added the output on my commpent

Comment: Search by `rtl8821ae`. You will find solutions.